Plug socket not working
My plug sockets are brand new but the top hole in one won't let me put the plug in any explanation please?

The usual problem is the plug is backwards, turn it around so the wide prong goes in the wide slot, or they have safety locks that need a ground prong to open/release.  Pictures will help.  A more rare problem is they are defective.

Might also be just tight and needs more of a push in(good).  Tight is good.

Do they have TR embossed anywhere on them?

New “safety” outlets suck, wiggle the plug & push harder.
